# Setting a button background resource with a .png from internal storage

Tags: android, user-interface, deprecated

I have a button that I want to set the background of using a png file from internal storage.  For android api 16 and up, this works fine:

```
filePath = getActivity().getFileStreamPath(colorCodes.get(i-1));
temp.setBackground(Drawable.createFromPath(filePath.toString()));
```

When running on an android tablet with 4.0.4, this part crashes the app with a nosuchmethod error (setBackground).  After a little research, I see that setBackground is only available for api 16+.  After looking around on SO and a few other places, it looks like I need to use setBackgroundDrawable (deprecated) or setBackgroundResource.  I tried this:

```
filePath = getActivity().getFileStreamPath(colorCodes.get(i-1));

if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 16) {
   temp.setBackgroundDrawable(Drawable.createFromPath(filePath.toString()));
} else {
   temp.setBackground(Drawable.createFromPath(filePath.toString()));
}
```

When logging it out, it shows that setBackgroundDrawable is running and not setBackground, but I get the same nosuchmethod error (setBackground).

The other option is setBackgroundResource, but it accepts an int and not a drawable.  Can I convert from drawable to int for this purpose?

What can I do here to set the background of the button to a file in internal storage for APIs < 16?

Thanks.

***EDIT - ok, this is working.  just missed a little part elsewhere in the code that had the same problem.  However, is using a deprecated method really the only way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Deprecation is a status applied to a computer software feature,
>   characteristic, or practice indicating it should be avoided, typically
>   because of it being superseded. The term is also sometimes used for a
>   feature, design, or practice that is permitted but no longer
>   recommended in other areas, such as hardware design or compliance to
>   building codes. [(source link)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deprecation)

Now we can answer your question.

Before API level 16 there is a method named `setBackgroundDrawable`. After API Level 16 google decided to write a new method `setBackground` for same purpose and recommend us to use new method. (Reason of this may be found by googling.)

You can use `setBackgroundDrawable` method for all api levels. There aren't any constraint for this. But using new method `setBackground` is recommended after API Level 16.

But you can only use `setBackground` method for devices which is running on API Level 16 or higher. So if you only implement `setBackground` method in your code, you are going to get `MethodNotFoundException` for devices which run below API Level 16.

To sum up; it is a best practice(for me it is a must) to use new methods then deprecated ones with supportted api version check such as;

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 16) {
   temp.setBackgroundDrawable(Drawable.createFromPath(filePath.toString()));
} else {
   temp.setBackground(Drawable.createFromPath(filePath.toString()));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not quite sure whether it is the only way to achieve this but in my opinion it is the correct one. Because the annotation @Deprecated defines the method to be superseded (in most cases) it automatically implies you can (I would even say should) use it to address older versions which are the targeted versions of this method.